# duplicate symbol _cpXYZ cocos2d-x v3.1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, cocos2d-x, xcode5.1

The codes compiles and works perfectly on iOS Simulator.
When i add "-ObjC" or "-all_load" in Targer -> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags and then compile and run, xcode gives my these errors:

```
duplicate symbol _cpSpacePointQuery in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
duplicate symbol _cpSpacePointQueryFirst in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
duplicate symbol _cpSpaceNearestPointQuery in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
duplicate symbol _cpSpaceNearestPointQueryNearest in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
duplicate symbol _cpSpaceSegmentQuery in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
duplicate symbol _cpSpaceSegmentQueryFirst in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
duplicate symbol _cpSpaceBBQuery in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
duplicate symbol _cpSpaceShapeQuery in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpSpaceQuery.o)
duplicate symbol _cpResetShapeIdCounter in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpShape.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpShape.o)
duplicate symbol _cpShapeInit in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpShape.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpShape.o)
duplicate symbol _cpShapeDestroy in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpShape.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpShape.o)
duplicate symbol _cpShapeFree in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpShape.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpShape.o)
duplicate symbol _cpShapeSetBody in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpShape.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpShape.o)
duplicate symbol _cpShapeCacheBB in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpShape.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpShape.o)
duplicate symbol _cpShapeUpdate in:
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libchipmunk iOS.a(cpShape.o)
    /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-frljocfxskmjcmesosyitnkinkmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx iOS.a(cpShape.o)
```

UPDATE:
I was adding ad SDKs and some of SDKs require -ObjC and -all_load flag. Removing -all_load fixed the issue. So, any having issue of like that can ignore -all_load flag from ad SDKs tutorial

Comment: Why are you adding those flags? Your question is tagged cocos2d-x.

Comment: I was adding ad SDKs and some of SDKs require -ObjC and -all_load flag. Removing -all_load fixed the issue.